# Return a value if user hides a column?

Tags: excel, vba

Ok so I have a pretty simple function:

```
Public Function CELLHIDDEN(col As Variant) As Integer
  Application.Volatile True
  x = 1
  If Range(col).ColumnWidth = 0 Then x = 0

  CELLHIDDEN = x
End Function
```

and I can put it in a cell like so:

```
=CELLHIDDEN("P5")
```

The problem is, it won't recalculate *UNLESS* I press enter somewhere else on the sheet.  From what I'm guessing the Application.Volitle makes it sensitive to such changes, but what I really want is for it to do something once you hide a column.

I'm basically grouping 5 columns, and I want to have something pop up that mentions that there's hidden columns when they disappear...

Answer (score 0):

The `Application.Volatile` makes your function recalculate whenever anything on your workbook recalculates, much like `NOW()`, `OFFSET()` or `INDIRECT()` which are considered *volatile* functions and are recalculated regardless of whether a change would appear to affect their result or not.

What you are looking for is a *trigger* for your function. Assuming that the hiding/revealing is performed on the worksheet and not through VBA then at least one of the cells in each row or column to be hidden must be selected. Since they won't be visible after the hide operation, another cell must be selected by the user to continue work. This would be the window of opportunity for either the `Workbook_SheetSelectionChange` or `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event macro to trigger a workbook, worksheet or even cell calculation event. For that matter, the event macro may even examine and report on the columns/rows being hidden or not itself.